# Insert 3 new rows at the end of the data keeping formatting using a Macro/Command button

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a sheet of data I update weekly, furthest most left column is the week of the year (1-52).

I want to, at the click of a button add the next week in keeping the formatting from the previous week.

Each week has 3 distinct rows with data that I manually enter daily. 
- First row is just a blank line coloured in grey to separate the weeks going down 
- Second row is a normal text box 
- Third row is a drop down menu.

At the moment I am manually highlighting the previous weeks 3 rows and using the small square in the bottom right to drag down to the new week and it copies all formatting, including adding the new week number (Previous week number + 1).

How can I do this using a Macro/button?

Edit here is the code from the Macro:

```
Sub NewWeek()
'
' NewWeek Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Range("A38:Q40").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A38:Q43"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A38:Q43").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You could do this with the macro recorder

Comment: I have tried to Macro record but the Macro then always refers to that specific group of 3 rows whenever I run it in the future, I want it automatically select the last 3 rows in the sheet (the last week(

Comment: I have edited original post to include the code

Comment: Can anyone else help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to copy the "lowest" three rows in `A:Q` each week, this will do that

```
Sub WeekEndUpdate()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A" & lastRow - 2 & ":Q" & lastRow)

    rng.AutoFill Destination:=rng.Resize(6), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I had to tweak it slightly after understanding what x1Up does...

Even though each week has 3 rows, in Column A I only had the week number on Row 2 (Row 1 and 3 were blank in Column A) so when it was executing the x1Up it wasn't seeing data in Row 1, 2 and 3 so was only copying from Row 2.

So I added a character into Row 1 and Row 3, Column A (hidden by changing text colour to match Cell fill colour) and kept Row 2 as the week number.

Comment: @Andrew great, I'm glad it was simple to get things workin' !